# A closed set is always a subset of ball with arbitrary center and radius $r>2 \cdot diam(A)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq X$. Let $B(x,r)$ be the
>   open ball with center $x \in X$ and radius $r>0$. The set $A$ is
>   closed, $diam(A)<r$ and also   $A \cap B(x,r) \neq \emptyset$
>
> Prove that $A \subseteq B(x,2r)$.

If $x \in A$ then it's rather obvious that any ball $B(x,r)$ contains the set $A$ so $A \subseteq B(x,2r)$. Now it remains to prove for $x \in X \setminus A$. From the condition $A \cap B(x,r) \neq \emptyset$ there is always a point from $A$ that is in the ball at the same time so at worst we will have that point be $y \in A$ such that $d(z,y) \leq r$ $\forall z \in A$ in which case the ball $B(x,2r)$ always contains the set $A$.

This is a very informal proof and it mostly comes from intuitive understanding. I'm not sure how to write a more formal one using the definitions of closed set, ball and the conditions. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in A\cap B(x,r)$. Then, for every $a\in A$,
$$
d(a,x) \leq d(a,y) + d(y,x) < r+r=2r,
$$
therefore $A\subset B(x,2r)$.

Comment: This seems right to me but it doesn't use the condition that $A$ is closed. Is this a necessary condition at all? I had my mind wrapped around it so hard I failed to see something this simple.

Comment: It's unnecessary